# Pushing static IP to OpenVPN client - Proxmox

Tags: ip, openvpn, proxmox

I installed Proxmox on a machine, and I want to make the web GUI available from Internet, so I can work on VMs when I travel.

I installed and configured OpenVPN on my Proxmox host (192.168.0.50) to do so, and tried to connect to it with my laptop, thanks to 4G connection sharing. It worked, but my laptop's ip is now 10.8.0.2, and it can't reach the proxmox web configurator.

I already tried to add a ccd directory with parameters for my client, but it still received 10.8.0.2.

I've tried multiple things, done researches, but I didn't managed to get trough.

Does anyone have any advice/suggestion on how pushing custom ip addresses ?

My server.conf file :

```
local 192.168.0.50
port 2899
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
explicit-exit-notify
client-config-dir ccd
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if [this](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/OpenVPN_in_LXC) will help you just try it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the thing is that I need OpenVPN to be installed on Proxmox's host, not on a VM it runs. I'm still going to check it out